# Drag&drop change source of dragged element

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I would like to know if it's possible to change the source of a dragged element.

I have a low definition image that can be dragged. I want to change its source by its high definition to send it to another application like Photoshop.

I read about the dataTransfert javascript API.

At first I tried to use the `DataTransfer.setData()` with image/jpeg MIME types but without success.

So I told myself that maybe I could change the source of the dragged element.
Here is what I tried

```html
<img id="MYTEST" ondragstart="dragStartHandler(event);" draggable="true" src="img/image_low.jpg" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    async function file_get_contents(uri) {
        let res = await fetch(uri),
        ret = await res.blob();
        return ret;
    }

    const dragStartHandler = async (e) => {
      let imageHigh = await file_get_contents("image_high.jpg");
      let imageHighFile = new File([imageHigh], 'image_high.jpg',{type: "image/jpeg"});
      e.dataTransfer.files[0] = imageHighFile;
    }
</script>
```

I saw that for security reason obviously it's not allowed to change anything into the fileList object.

There is a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this solution will work for your purposes, but wrapping your image in a hyperlink tag may work. This should cause the linked URL to be dropped when dragged instead of the image. I cannot guarantee that your browser can interact directly with Photoshop, or that a URL would translate to an image when doing so, but, within the context of the browser, this solution seems to be successful. If you add an onclick event which prevents the event's default action, the link won't open when the user clicks it:

```
<a href="img/image_high.jpg" onclick="event.preventDefault();">
 <img src="img/image_low.jpg"/>
</a>
```

For a live example, see the following:

```html
<a href="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1455185376876826625/s1AjSxph_400x400.jpg" onclick="event.preventDefault();">
 <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
</a>
```

Alternatively, you could hide your high definition image in front of your low definition image -- if you set the high definition image opacity to 0, but make sure its the same size as the low definition one, the user would interact with it when dragging, -- but then you would need to load both images, and it may be better, in that case, to only use the high definition image.

Comment: this solution is suitable as you pointed it in browser context but effectively will not work for my purpose and it'll not be possible to load high definition instead low without decreasing app performances (nearly 50 high definition images per page)